# Access to closing options for Java admin SDK Firestore instance

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

If I write a large amount of data to my Firestore database, using a Firestore instance created by

```
GoogleCredentials myCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/myPath/myCredentialsFile.json"));
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                             .setCredentials(myCredentials)
                             .setDatabaseUrl("https://myProject.firebaseio.com")
                             .build();
 FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options, "myFirebaseApp");
 Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(app);
```

, I receive the error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Firestore client has already been closed
```

Writing smaller amounts of data works just fine, though.

If I instead create a Firestore instance from FirestoreOptions, like

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance()
                                       .toBuilder()
                                       .setProjectId("myProject")
                                       .setCredentials(myCredentials)
                                       .build();
Firestore fs = firestoreOptions.getService();
```

, I don't have this problems, even for the large amounts of data. Apparently, some default settings for db makes it close after a certain amount of time or workload, and these  settings do not occur in firestoreOptions.

I tried to set the above FirestoreOptions in my FirebaseOptions:

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                             .setFirestoreOptions(firestoreOptions)
                             .setCredentials(myCredentials)
                             .setDatabaseUrl("https://myProject.firebaseio.com")
                             .build();
```

, but I still get the same error message. So, it seems that either the closing settings are not embedded in firestoreOptions, or they are being overridden by some default values in the last line of the creation of db.

So, can I set db not to close until I call db.close()?

Comment: This is very strange. Both methods should return the same `Firestore` object. Can you add some more information how to replicate the issue? Is it transaction or just writes? Are they writing continuously or there are some idle times?

Comment: @vitooh: There is a list of writes, and no idle time. Anyway, I tried to add the following InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider to firestoreOptions: `InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider channelProvider = InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.newBuilder()
                                                                .setKeepAliveTime(Duration.ofSeconds(3600))
                                                                .setKeepAliveTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                                                                .build();`, but this did not change anything.

Comment: @vitooh: The two Firestore objects are different: fs does not bypass Firestore security rules, whereas db does so. But if I replace `FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()` by `FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()`, in the creation of fs, it also bypasses security rules.

Comment: I think you should raise this as bug. I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report)  will be proper link